# Linking error: can't figure how to pass/receive arrays as function arguments

Tags: c++, linker

I'm working on a small OpenGL demo that reads orientation of a physical sensor (in quaternion format) and consequently rotates an object on screen.  Now I'm trying to transform the quaternion-form rotation into a rotation 4x4 matrix.  I found a small algorithm online that does that.  However, I have a hard time processing my quaternion into matrices because I don't understand how to pass arrays around C++ functions.

So I'm trying to do this:

```
#include "MatrixMath.h"

// somewhere in my render loop
float aRotationMatrix[16];
readRotation(aRotationMatrix);
```

The `readRotation` function is defined as:

```
void readRotation(float *a4x4Flat16Matrix){
   sQuaternionReader.read();
   float aQuaternion[4];

   aQuaternion[0] = sQuaternionReader.getQuarternionX();
   aQuaternion[1] = sQuaternionReader.getQuarternionY();
   aQuaternion[2] = sQuaternionReader.getQuarternionZ();
   aQuaternion[3] = sQuaternionReader.getQuarternionW();

   float *aMatrix = a4x4Flat16Matrix;

   fromQuaternionToMatrix(aQuaternion, aMatrix);  // this is declared faulty by the linker

}
```

When I try to compile, the linker gives me this error:

```
./src/main/CupNPlate.cpp:151: error: undefined reference to 'fromQuaternionToMatrix(float*, float*)'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [CupNPlate] Error 1
```

The `fromQuaternionToMatrix` function is declared in a file named "MatrixMath.h":

```
#ifndef MATRIXMATH_H_
#define MATRIXMATH_H_

void fromQuaternionToMatrix( float *aQuaternion,
         float *a4x4Flat16Matrix );

#endif
```

And implemented in a file named "MatrixMath.cpp":

```
#include "MatrixMath.h"

void fromQuaternionToMatrix( float *aQuaternion,
         float *a4x4Flat16Matrix ){
   // x := 0, y := 1, z := 2, w := 3
   float x2 = aQuaternion[0] * aQuaternion[0];
   float y2 = aQuaternion[1] * aQuaternion[1];
   float z2 = aQuaternion[2] * aQuaternion[2];
   float xy = aQuaternion[0] * aQuaternion[1];
   float xz = aQuaternion[0] * aQuaternion[2];
   float yz = aQuaternion[1] * aQuaternion[2];
   float wx = aQuaternion[3] * aQuaternion[0];
   float wy = aQuaternion[3] * aQuaternion[1];
   float wz = aQuaternion[3] * aQuaternion[2];

   a4x4Flat16Matrix[0] =  1.0f - 2.0f * (y2 + z2);
   a4x4Flat16Matrix[1] =  2.0f * (xy - wz);
   a4x4Flat16Matrix[2] =  2.0f * (xz + wy);
   a4x4Flat16Matrix[3] =  0.0f;

   a4x4Flat16Matrix[4] =  2.0f * (xy + wz);
   a4x4Flat16Matrix[5] =  1.0f - 2.0f *(x2 + z2);
   a4x4Flat16Matrix[6] =  2.0f * (yz - wx);
   a4x4Flat16Matrix[7] =  0.0f;

   a4x4Flat16Matrix[8] =  2.0f * (xz - wy);
   a4x4Flat16Matrix[9] =  2.0f * (yz + wx);
   a4x4Flat16Matrix[10] =  1.0f - 2.0f * (x2 + y2);
   a4x4Flat16Matrix[11] =  0.0f;

   a4x4Flat16Matrix[12] =  0.0f;
   a4x4Flat16Matrix[13] =  0.0f;
   a4x4Flat16Matrix[14] =  0.0f;
   a4x4Flat16Matrix[15] =  1.0f;
}
```

The linker tells me `undefined reference to 'fromQuaternionToMatrix(float*, float*)'` but the signature of my function is exactly `fromQuaternionToMatrix( float *aQuaternion,
         float *a4x4Flat16Matrix )`, so I don't understand what it is whining about.  The compiler gives me no errors.

Comment: Are you compiling `MatrixMath.cpp`?

Comment: You have linkage problem. Your array passing is fine. Make sure you compile and link all necessary files.

Comment: In what file readrotation function is defined?

Comment: Try to #include "MatrixMath" in file where readRotation is declared

Comment: @spin_eight - If `MatrixMath` was not included a compiler error would occur as the identifier would not be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It not the **signature** of the function that is the problem, it's the **inability to link to any implementation**.

If you were passing the wrong arguments to the function you would get a **compile time error**. What you are getting here is a **link time error**. The linker cannot find any implementation for the function declared as `fromQuaternionToMatrix(float*, float*)`

In Visual Studio (I can't comment on other ides), you need to ensure that your **`.cpp`** file is added to your project. Otherwise if you are using a lib you will need to **reference** the library either in the project settings, or in the code.

```
#pragma comment(lib, "LibFileName");
```

Comment: I think I might have forgot to add MatrixMath.cpp to my Makefile...  I'll have to double check when I get back home... I feel preemptively ashamed.

Comment: This was it.  I was giving `MatrixMath.o` to the linker but forgot to actually compile `MatrixMath.cpp` =S